# Human readable key names for characters

Tags: dart

I want to trigger some code if the 'A' key is pressed:

```
document.on.keyDown.add((event) { 
    if (event.keyIdentifier == 'U+0041') {
       ...
    }
});
```

Using the unicode code (`U+0041`) of the character is not very readable. Is there any method I can use to convert the code to a character or vice versa? I would like to do something like this:

```
document.on.keyDown.add((event) { 
    if (event.keyIdentifier == unicodeCode('A')) {
       ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
  document.on.keyPress.add((KeyboardEvent event) {
    final String char = new String.fromCharCodes([event.charCode]);
    print('Key: $char');

    if (event.keyIdentifier == 'U+0041') {
      print('$char pressed.');
    }

    if (char == 'a') {
      print('Lowercase "a" has been pressed.');
    }
  });
```

Currently the `keyDown` event doesn't provide the appropriate *charCodes*.